# How to catch and save exception in .net?

Tags: .net, exception, try-catch

I want to catch and save an exception in log file.

How can I implement this myself?

Comment: Depends on how and where you want the data saved. The logic would happen in the CATCH portion of a try catch (e.ErrorMessage). You could then save it to a file, or store it in a database or XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at the NLog project : http://nlog-project.org/

Assuming you know how to catch an exception, you just need to log it with NLog, which has multiple configuration options to write the exception details (or a message) to file, event viewer, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know how to catch Exceptions. Most basic example would be something like:

```
try
{
    // ... Do some work here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    File.WriteAllText("C:\\ExceptionFile" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".txt", ex.Message);
}
```

This way your error message will be written to a txt file on your C:\ drive.
You could also add, or choose to write the StackTrace, you'd probably want that.

Also if you would want it throughout your whole application you are going to need a much more elegant solution, something with a log class or similar.